# What is an object constructor?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand the process of creating an object with the Object Constructor.

After reading my javascript book, sources online, the MDN and MSDN, I can't decide how best to define the object constructor.

```
function Person(first, last, age, eyecolor) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eyecolor
}
```

In the code above, should I be thinking of the Object Constructor as:

- The entire function and all of the code that goes with it?
- JUST the function "person()"
- Or is it simply a term given to whatever behind-the-scenes things the JavaScript engine has to do to "create" my object in the memory?

It seems like creating objects with the Object Constructor is like creating an object template, which you can later fill in while simultaneously creating that object based on the previously defined "object template".

Please feel free to nitpick and help me accurately define this term and completely understand it.

Comment: It's a Constructor function, which becomes an Object when you create a `new` instance.

Comment: By convention, constructor names are capitalized, like `Person`. It's a way to remember you must use `new` when you call it.

Comment: You can also create a `new` instance of an Object literal, like: `if(!Object.create){Object.create = function(o){function F(){}; F.prototype = o; return new F;}};`. Now just use `var pers = {prop:'value'}, newPers = Object.create(pers);`. Of course, you cannot pass arguments to an Object.

Comment: What is the distinction you are making between "the entire function and all the code that goes with it" and "JUST the function"? The function by definition includes "all the code that goes with it".

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @Oriol, I will remember to capitalize constructor names from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term `constructor function` or `object constructor` refers to all the code in your `person` function and the expectation that this code will be used with the `new` operator so it will be given a new object that `this` points to.  It is a function in javascript that is designed to be used a certain way.

It's worth understanding that a constructor function in Javascript is just a normal-everyday function that is designed to work as a constructor and designed to be called with the `new` operator.  Because it's designed to be called with the `new` operator, it assumes that it is given a brand-spanking new object that `this` points to.

The code inside the constructor function needs to do only what is required to properly initialize the object.  That could be anything from nothing to pages and pages of code - that is entirely dependent upon the application.

The other powerful aspect of constructor functions is that you can assign them a prototype and by doing so, you are telling the JS engine what default properties you want the object to have when the JS engine creates the initial object before passing it off to the constructor function.

So, in your example:

```
function Person(first, last, age, eyecolor) {
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastName = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eyecolor
}
```

You can add some methods to a prototype:

```
Person.prototype = {
    getFullName: function() {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    },
    incrementAge: function() {
        ++this.age;
    }
};
```

Now, when you create a new `Person` object (I've switched to uppercase as is the usual convention with constructor functions in Javascript), you will get an object with both the properties that your code assigns in your constructor, but it will also have the methods that are assign to the prototype.

```
var p = new Person("Ted", "Williams", 39, "blue");
var fullname = p.getFullName();    // returns "Ted Williams"
```

It is generally more efficient in Javascript to use the prototype for methods rather than to assign each method one by one in the constructor and prototypes provide one means for inheritance too.

Comment: Thank you for the great information @jfriend00. So you are saying that any function can "become" an object constructor IF it is being invoked by the `new` keyword? Additionally, would I be correct in thinking that the `new` keyword is the "real" object constructor - or at least the `new` keyword is the prerequisite to an object constructor?

Comment: @JonathonAndrews - It is also possible to create a new object without using the `new` operator by having a regular function that just returns a new object that was created in the function.  This is often called a factory function, but accomplishes the same thing as a constructor function.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put a constructor is a function that builds objects of a given class. For example, if you have a class named Person then the following code could represent a parameterized constructor for that class.

```
 function Person(first, last, age, eyecolor) {
        this.firstName = first;
        this.lastName = last;
        this.age = age;
        this.eyeColor = eyecolor
    }
```

Here we have a parameterized constructor for a class named Person. The constructor is known as a "parameterized" constructor because we are passing in parameters, in this case 4 parameters named first, last, age and eyecolor. The constructor takes these 4 values and sets the firstName, lastName, age and eyeColor fields for the object built in question.

A default constructor is always called when an object is created in a program. This parameterized constructor allows us to build an object with default values at the time of creation rather than setting them with default values as a default constructor would.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the 'official' definition is, but I think all of your points apply. An Object Constructor is essentially a function that 'contructs' the object. It does this through the code inside the constructor function, which may use other code (ie: through function calls) to construct the object. Technically, the object contructor is 'just' the funciton `person`. But in reality, the function needs the code inside it to work, so you can't just ignore it.

Also, it is a naming custom in js to name Object constructors with a capital letter.

```
function Person(first, last, age, eyecolor) {
  this.firstName = first;
  this.lastName = last;
  this.age = age;
  this.eyeColor = eyecolor;
}

var jim = new Person("Jimmy", "Smith", 22, "blue");
```

These are worth reading if you want to know more:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

"Constructor" refers to a *role* that a function serves. All constructors are simply functions, and any function can be used as a constructor by calling it with `new`. A constructor is a function which is written with the intention of having it be invoked by `new`.

When a function is used as a constructor (i.e., called with `new`), the invoked function has its `this` value set to a newly-created object. That newly created `this` object is an object whose prototype chain begins with the invoked function's `prototype` value (so, in your case, for the newly-created `this`, it is true that `this.__proto__ === person.prototype`). This means that any properties or methods on `person.prototype` can be accessed directly on the newly-created object.

Finally, if the constructor function does not explicitly return an object, it will return its newly-created `this` object.